# USB Media stopped working from one day to the next on 2 PCs (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, nemo

frome one day to the next Ubuntu 14.04 stopped recognizing any USB media. Plugging in a USB stick or my Android phone plays the familiar klick sound but no device is listed in nemo or the native file manager.

Yet, the device is listed in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
HERE---->Bus 002 Device 007: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b221 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd integrated camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And it does show up upon `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e7ed2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2000895      999424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2002942   300003327   149000193    5  Extended
/dev/sda3       300003328   500117503   100057088   83  Linux
/dev/sda5         2002944    20000767     8998912   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6        20002816    90001407    34999296   83  Linux
/dev/sda7        90003456   260001791    84999168   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       260003840   280002559     9999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       280004608   300003327     9999360   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 8189 MB, 8189378560 bytes
224 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1133 cylinders, total 15994880 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
HERE----> /dev/sdb1              32    15994879     7997424    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Strangely, this happened at the very same time on 2 PCs both running Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome3.
It is definitely not the USB Media. I tried 2 different USB sticks as well as my Android Phone!
However, plugging in a USB Mouse into the same USB plug works like a charm.

I am really puzzled!
What is wrong? Thanks!

PS: Output form `dmesg`:

```
[  827.926196] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  827.926376] scsi13 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[  828.927655] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  828.928340] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  828.929768] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] 15994880 512-byte logical blocks: (8.18 GB/7.62 GiB)
[  828.930884] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  828.930897] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[  828.932008] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  828.939865]  sdb: sdb1
[  828.943416] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

EDIT:

PPS:

The USB stick and my phone are also listed in the Ubuntu Disks programme (former Disks Utility?).

Answer (score 2):

USB sticks and android phones are two very different beasts from the OS's perspective. Phones use mtpfs in order to connect to the OS, while usb sticks work as normal storage media. Try to mount them manually.`mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt && nemo /mnt`
See if it works. when you're done `umount /mnt`

Comment: Yes, this works, but only as root.

Comment: But why doesn't nemo manage to mount the device?

Comment: Automound might be disabled. What does `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.media-handling`  say?

Comment: ``org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open true`` and
``org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount true``

Comment: ok, that's obviously not the problem. Do you have gvfs-afc and gvfs-mtp installed?

Comment: what about `gsettings list-recursively org.cinnamon.desktop.media-handling`?

Comment: Nope AFAIK neither gvfs-afc (that's Apple stuff right?) nor gvfs-mtp, ``gsettings list-recursively org.cinnamon.desktop.media-handling`` gives ``No such schema 'org.cinnamon.desktop.media-handling'``

Comment: No, it's not from apple, it' from gnome: gnome virtual file system: [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_manager_functionality#Mounting)

Comment: Sure, what I meant was that afc is the backend for apple phones. Ah sorry, so ``locate gvfs-afc`` does return ``/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor`` (similar for mtp)

Comment: Ok, then please check if your device isn't hidden: `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules` under "Devices which should not be display in the user interface"

Comment: I don't have a ``80-udisks2.rules`` file, actually I am already mssing the ``/usr/lib/udev`` folder.

Comment: One last thing you could try is just reinstall nemo...